# How to explain the logic process of the numpy's output?

Tags: python, numpy

I am learning numpy from the start page : https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html
There is a confusing part that makes me stop.

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> b1 = np.array([False, True, True])         # first dim selection
>>> b2 = np.array([True, False, True, False])  # second dim selection
>>> a[b1, b2]
array([ 4, 10])
```

Could you please provide any hints or explains to help me understand this logic?
The output that I expect is

```
array([[ 4,  6],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

Comment: indexing with multiple boolean arrays cane be confusing.

Comment: same as `b[[1,2] ,[0,2]]`.  Uses `np.nonzero(b1)[0]` and `np.nonzero(b2)[0]`

Comment: to get the block `b[[[1],[2]], [0,2] ]`.  Think how the arrays/lists `broadcast` together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to achieve what you want is to apply your masks sequentially. In other words,

```py
a[b1,:][:,b2]

# [[ 4  6]
# [ 8 10]]
```

It seems like you are assuming that `b1` determines which rows must be selected and `b2` determines which columns must be selected. This is a fair assumption, but numpy masks broadcast differently. What is in fact happening when you pass *both at the same time*, is that they get converted to indices. So

```
b1 = np.array([False, True, True]) -> [1,2]
b2 = np.array([True, False, True, False]) -> [0,2]
```

Which indeed gives the "weird" behavior:

```py
b1 = [1,2]
b2 = [0,2]

a[b1,b2] # [ 4 10]
```